# Django background infinite loop process management

Tags: python, django, multithreading, postgresql, celery

I'm having trouble trying to figure out the best way to run a background process with Django with specific requirements.

What I would like to be able to do:

- Process(es) run(s) on an infinite loop once started (will need 2 background processes, no more, no less)
- Start/Stop/Get_Status of each process
- Able to access Postgres DB (rules out subprocess module(I think))
- Even when no users have accessed the website, the process continues to run in the background if started.

---

**Edit:**

- **When the task that I need to run starts, it has to initialize itself with DB information in order to gather what it needs.  After initialization, it compares new information with it's prior results in order to get a delta value.  Unfortunately re-initializing each time the task runs defeats this purpose and it must run in a continuous loop unless intentionally stopped by the user.**

---

Options I have considered but haven't been able to find reliable documentation on how I can do what I want to be able to do:

- Celery
- RQ
- django-background-task

My requirements.txt in virtualenv (currently trying to get celery working):

```
  1 amqp==1.4.7
  2 anyjson==0.3.3
  3 billiard==3.3.0.21
  4 celery==3.1.19
  5 Django==1.8.6
  6 django-crispy-forms==1.5.2
  7 kombu==3.0.29
  8 psycopg2==2.6.1
  9 pytz==2015.7
 10 redis==2.10.5
 11 requests==2.8.1
 12 uWSGI==2.0.11.2
 13 wheel==0.24.0
```

If I didn't supply enough information about my problem, I apologize in advance (this is my first time posting).

Comment: Why the background process need to be written in Django???

Comment: More to the point, why do you need processes running on an infinite loop, and why specifically two? What exactly are you doing in those processes?

Comment: @AngelCruijff, It is the framework that I chose to do the rest of the project in.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, It is a portion of the app that I'm making to do a recurring scan on domains/websites/ips belonging to myself to check for publicly viewable malicious activity.  It will be using "dig", "whois", and "wget".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Celery is just for you. You can take a look at [pereodic tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) for some background tasks.

Also it's very easy to start using Celery with Django. You can start learning it [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html).

Comment: Thank you for the links pythad.  I looked at the periodic tasks and it doesn't seem like either the beat or cron scheduler will work for me as from what I understand is that it re-creates the task each time it is run?

When the task that I need to run starts, it has to initialize itself with DB information in order to gather what it needs.  After initialization, it compares new information with it's prior results in order to get a delta value.  Unfortunately re-initializing each time the task runs defeats this purpose.  

I'm sorry, I should have been more clear! I will update the question.

Comment: @Vealor, task is just a python function, you can do anything in it. You can get data from db inside the function, compare to something and return anything you want.

Comment: I understand, my only concern is that I have to use system commands such as dig, whois and wget.  When the task is to be run anew, I need to "zero-out" all prior data so I can re-initialize a baseline for what I would get from running those commands, then begin a comparative task until the process is stopped by the user.

Comment: After thinking about it for a bit.... I think that I might be able to get it working with Beat if I store all gathered information in the DB and only force an initialization when a UI button is pressed and not on each task creation.  Does that mean that I would be able to separate each task and have multiple tasks running? So if I had hypothetically 200 system commands to run, I could do each using subprocess and also task each one individually in a queue?  It seems like that is a better approach than the one I had initially envisioned.....

Comment: @Vealor, yes, you can try this. You can create tasks on some clicks and place them into a queue.

Comment: instead of clicking, I'm assuming it is possible to have celery do "for entry in DB: create new Beat task"?  If not, I will likely have to keep track of the last time things were run, and have say: a Beat go per minute querying which tasks have to be run (because some tasks have say a 5 minute turnover, and some say a 12), then it can create tasks within that beat to be run in the queue if they match the correct runtime.